# Why Is Apache The Primary Webserver In Docker Containers (for PHP)

Tags: php, apache, nginx, docker

When I look at docker projects almost everyone goes with Apache within a container to serve up PHP based apps. For example Piwik.

https://github.com/piwik/docker-piwik

Yes, most setups have some sort of proxy server in front of the docker containers (typically Nginx).

Just wondering why most people use Apache within containers instead of a lighter weight more modern server such as Nginx.

Only thing I can think of is Mod-PHP as PHP can be built right into Apache while Nginx required php-fpm. Adding php-fpm and Nginx into the same container takes a bit more work (got to start two services).

Wondering if there are any other reasons Apache seems to be more of a standard within PHP based docker containers.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. You may want to find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: In a nutshell, PHP and Apache have been together for a long, long time. More admins are familiar with Apache than any other webserver in the world.